# Can i have Given after When and Then in BDD?

Tags: bdd

I have some extended scenario for an already existing test case.
Existing test case has Given, When , Then.
Now, i want to extend after this case.

So, can i have like Given, When, Then, Given, When, Then.
Hope this does not break in executing or in any step_impl.
Also, suggest if this is not good practice to have.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the tool you use to execute the steps.

If you are using Cucumber, you can mix the order of `Given/When/Then/And/But` however you like.

If you mix the keywords in a some interesting way, you are possible destroying one of the important properties of Gherkin, the ability to function as a living documentation. It is possible to create a scenario that is unreadable this way.

What it sounds to me that you would like to do is to create a new scenario that operates on a higher level of abstraction rather than extending a small scenario into a larger scenario. Or possible transform your current scenario to a higher abstraction level.

Having two scenarios at different abstraction level is not necessarily a bad thing. It documents and executes your product from two different perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from using just the keyword `Given` for every step in your scenario. It won't make any sense - but the gherkin parser won't care.

If you want to have well structured scenarios that functions as clear-cut tests when run, the each scenario should ideally have one `Given`, followed by one `When` followed by one `Then.

After all, Given/When/Then simply map to the more traditional three stages of a test: Arrange/Act/Assert. It wouldn't make sense to write a test with the steps: Arrange, Act Then arrange a bit more, then act a bit more - then assert, then rearrange etc.

No, if you have more than one When or Then - you have a separate use-case/example/test.